# How to create a simple "hello world" Samsung S6 edge app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am wanting to create a simple app which will show some information on the Samsung S6s edge panel, and so I am starting to try to get the samsung exmaple running.

I've developed android application before (some time ago), but looking through the Samsung documentation I am lost, i'm sure i'm not the only one.

**What I have tried so far**

I have downloaded the samsung look sdk here: http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#look

I can then import a project into eclipse from the samples called "EdgeScreenSampleApplication", and using android 19 I am able to compile it. However, I cannot run it on any emulator. I assume I need some special emulator to show the 'edge', but I cannot find one. When I run it on a Nexus emulator, I get:

```
[2015-03-21 21:01:33 - EdgeScreenSampleApplication] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2015-03-21 21:01:33 - EdgeScreenSampleApplication] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-03-21 21:01:33 - EdgeScreenSampleApplication] Launch canceled!
```

Now I am stuck, do I need a particular emulator? How can I get this thing running? I'd like to run it, then I can dig in to look at the code and see how it is working. Of course I do not have a Samsung S6 to test on as they are not yet released.

Comment: it's out of date - the S6 is now available